# GCC recommends a strange implementation for max macro

Tags: c, gcc

so , I was reading GCC documentation until I reached **Statements and Declarations in Expressions** section 6.1 , [follow this link to reach the section I am talking about](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs).

I came to these strange lines where GCC states that

> This feature is especially useful in making macro definitions “safe” (so that they evaluate each operand exactly once). For example, the “maximum” function is commonly defined as a macro in standard C as follows:
>
> `#define max(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))`
>
> But this definition computes either a or b twice, with bad results if the operand has side effects. In GNU C, if you know the type of the operands (here taken as int), you can avoid this problem by defining the macro as follows:
>
> `#define maxint(a,b)  ({int _a = (a), _b = (b); _a > _b ? _a : _b; })`

from my understand , GCC recommends knowing the type of the arguments, now I have many questions in my head.

1. why do I have to know the type of the arguments ? I mean C macros are just like text replacements , so I think `max(a,b)` will work just fine with any primitive data type whether it's integer, float, double, etc..
2. I don't know how will `maxint(a,b)` work , I mean it's a strange signature of ternary operator , I mean for example in the next lines of code:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   #define maxint(a,b) \
     ({int _a = (a), _b = (b); _a > _b ? _a : _b; })

   int main()
   {
       int x = 5;
       int y = 10;
       int z = maxint(x , y);
       printf("z = %d",z);
   }
   ```

**z value will be 10** , which is a correct answer, and the next lines are the lines generated
after preprocessing done by the compiler of the above code:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 10;
    int z = ({int _a = (x), _b = (y); _a > _b ? _a : _b; });
    printf("z = %d",z);
    return 0;
}
```

my problem is in this line `int z = ({int _a = (x), _b = (y); _a > _b ? _a : _b; });` , how does this line evaluate z to be 10 , I mean It's just a block of lines , there is no return value. I only see this line when evaluating at runtime to be

`int z = ({int _a = (5), _b = (10);  10; });`
as whole ternary operation will be replaced by the value 10,as **(5 > 10 ? 5 : 10)** will be replaced by 10, which doesn't make sense to me to assign a block of code to a primitive data type (which is **z** in my case)

3. they said in the quoted lines above

> But this definition computes either a or b twice

talking about this macro `max(a,b)` , I don't understand how does this macro computes either a or  b twice and how did macro `maxint(a,b)` solve this problem ?

Comment: What do you think happens on `max(x++, --y)`?

Comment: Consider this code: `max(printf("a"), printf("b"))` vs. `maxint`. How many characters are printed?

Comment: Apparently, a construct `({ /* statements */ })` can be parsed by gcc as an *expression* whose value is the value of its last statement. This must be a proprietary extension of the C language. This construct is somewhat redundant to inline functions; inline keyword or not, modern compilers should inline code for a one-line function `int max(int a, int b) { return a > b ? a : b; }`, obviating the need for such a non-portable kludge.

Comment: @KamilCuk, oh now I understand , the value of z will be 8 as y has been decremented twice, so that's one of side effects of using this micro

Comment: The idea that the return value (also of functions) is by default the value of the last statement/expression occurs e.g. in Algol68. It's quite handy and, in a way, natural.

Comment: Just wrote inline equivalent to this macro. It's at least 15% shorter and 100% more legible.

Comment: GCC extensions tend to work like this: "Hi guys I invented a new feature! Does anyone know of a problem that this feature solves. Umm.... let me think...." That link is exactly like that - there exists no sane reason why you would use statement expressions over functions. All that's achieved is questionable type safety and non-portable code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why do I have to know the type of the arguments ?

To evaluate the arguments *once*, in assignment.

( And you don't, you can use another gcc extension `__auto_type` or `__typeof__`. )

> I mean it's a strange signature of ternary operator

It's a gcc extension called statement expression https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html .

> It's just a block of lines , there is no return value

And from that documentation: `The last thing in the compound statement should be an expression followed by a semicolon; the value of this subexpression serves as the value of the entire construct`. The value of `_a > _b ? _a : _b;` is the last, and it serves as the "return value" of `({...})`.

> how does this macro computes either a or b twice and how did macro maxint(a,b) solve this problem ?

Is explained in macro pitfalls in gcc documentation https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Duplication-of-Side-Effects.html#Duplication-of-Side-Effects .

> Many C programs define a macro min, for “minimum”, like this:
>
> #define min(X, Y)  ((X) < (Y) ? (X) : (Y))
>
> When you use this macro with an argument containing a side effect, as
> shown here,
>
> next = min (x + y, foo (z));
>
> it expands as follows:
>
> next = ((x + y) < (foo (z)) ? (x + y) : (foo (z)));

Answer (score 4):

The **gcc** doc is correct about one thing:

> For example, the “maximum” function is commonly defined as a macro in standard C as follows:
>
> ```
>  #define max(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
> ```
>
> But this definition computes either `a` or `b` twice, with bad results if the operand has side effects.

Yet the proposed solution is ill advised:

```
#define maxint(a,b)  ({int _a = (a), _b = (b); _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

This macro  illustrates the compiler's statement expression extension and will indeed evaluate the macro arguments exactly once, which is the goal, but the macro will fail on this simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define maxint(a,b)  ({int _a = (a), _b = (b); _a > _b ? _a : _b; })

int main() {
    int a = 1, _a = 2;
    printf("max = %d\n", maxint(a, _a));
    printf("max = %d\n", maxint(_a, a));
    return 0;
}
```

The above code outputs `max = 1` then `max = 2` (!)

Writing macros is tricky and error prone, making them safe is **extremely** difficult. The only sound advice for this matter is: *use a function*, possibly making it `static inline` to request inline expansion, albeit modern compilers may inline it even without these qualifiers:

```
int maxint(int a, int b) { return a > b ? a : b; }
```

Note that it is possible in C99 to use a macro to achieve some level of type genericity:

```
#define DEFINE_MAX(name, T) T name(T a, T b) { return a > b ? a : b; }
DEFINE_MAX(max_bool, _Bool)
DEFINE_MAX(max_char, char)
DEFINE_MAX(max_schar, signed char)
DEFINE_MAX(max_uchar, unsigned char)
DEFINE_MAX(max_short, short)
DEFINE_MAX(max_ushort, unsigned short)
DEFINE_MAX(max_int, int)
DEFINE_MAX(max_uint, unsigned)
DEFINE_MAX(max_long, long)
DEFINE_MAX(max_ulong, unsigned long)
DEFINE_MAX(max_llong, long long)
DEFINE_MAX(max_ullong, unsigned long long)
DEFINE_MAX(max_float, float)
DEFINE_MAX(max_double, double)
#undef DEFINE_MAX
#undef max
#define max(a,b) _Generic((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b), \
                   _Bool: max_bool(a, b),        \
                    char: max_char(a, b),        \
             signed char: max_schar(a, b),       \
           unsigned char: max_uchar(a, b),       \
                   short: max_short(a, b),       \
          unsigned short: max_ushort(a, b),      \
                     int: max_int(a, b),         \
                unsigned: max_uint(a, b),        \
                    long: max_long(a, b),        \
           unsigned long: max_ulong(a, b),       \
               long long: max_llong(a, b),       \
      unsigned long long: max_ullong(a, b),      \
                   float: max_float(a, b),       \
                  double: max_double(a, b),      \
                 default: "bad type for max"(a, b))
```

Comment: This is a good answer. Though for extra type safety I'd probably do the _Generic check on each operand in turn. Since binary `+` type promotes both operands, there might be foreseen implicit promotion hiccups when passing small integer types to the macro.

Comment: @Lundin: operands are indeed promoted if they have a type with a lesser rank than `int`, but this is intended to reduce the number of functions. Is is possible to avoid this implicit promotion by writing `_Generic((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b), ...)` and implement functions for `short`, `unsigned short`, `char`, `signed char`m `unsigned char` and `_Bool`.

Comment: @Lundin: thanks for the edit, I just changed the expression from `(a)+(b)` to `(a)*(b)` to ensure both operands have arithmetic type, but this actually prevents applying the macro to pointers.